# can't clone github project to my server

Tags: git, github

Im trying to clone a project from git hub to my server
and getting this error when trying to clone a project.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

command: git clone git@github.com:user_name/project_name.git

I looked at the web and says that I need to generate public key and insert it to my project sorry do you know tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: Did you actually type in "gitproject", or did you type a real location of a git repository, such as "git@github.com:user_name/project_name.git"?

Comment: I have type the real location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github help pages tell you all about :

- generating a pair of SSH keys
- adding your *public* key to your github account

Right there : https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys
Have fun !

SSH key pairs are a very important authentication mechanism, you should definitely check it out at some point. :)